# mod_rewrite not mapping url properly

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite to tidy up my url

There is a rule that translate to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$            /search?type=$1&query=$2 [L]

/search?type=title&query=me
/search/title/me
```

However this does not work, when I go to the above url `/search/title/me` I can not get the parameters `type` and `query`

If i change the rewrite rule to

```
RewriteRule ^search2/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$           /search?type=$1&query=$2 [L]
```

it works fine and I'm able to get all the paramaters.
I do not understand how this can be happening.

Help me please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to `MultiViews` option. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Disable it by using this line at the start of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: I added this at beginning of the .htaccess file and now I get a page not found error

Comment: Is this the only rule `RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search?type=$1&query=$2 [L]`? And is `/search/` a directory?

Comment: It is the only rule, I only have 3 lines in the .htaccess file and there is no folder called search

Comment: Ok then what is `/search`? Is it a PHP file? is `domain.com/search?type=title&query=me` working for you in browser?

Comment: yes it's a php file, it works fine the way you mentioned, I've tried adding it to the rule just in case, it makes no difference.

Comment: ok then rule should be: `RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$            /search.php?type=$1&query=$2 [L,QSA]` and you need to use `domain.com/search/title/me` in browsers. Where is this .htaccess located? Is it even enabled?